# How to redirect specific extentionless endpoint to another endpoint with extension

Tags: php, .htaccess, ubuntu, apache2

I want to redirect `myapp.com/foo` to `myapp.com/redirect.php`

/foo is non existing endpoint

I have the following `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # This is not working
    RewriteRule ^foo /redirect.php [R=301,NC,L]

    # Enfore SSL - This works
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?myapp\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is /foo a web directory?

Comment: @starkeen /foo is a non existent endpoint

Comment: How exactly is it “not working”? Does no redirect happen, or does anything else go wrong after that? You really actually want an _external_ redirect? If so you need to be aware that you would lose any POST data (if that is the actual problem case), because the client will follow that external 301 redirect by making a GET request for the new resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add $ after foo then anything will change?

```
RewriteRule ^foo$ redirect.php [R=301,L]
```

or with RewriteBase

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^foo$ redirect.php [R=301,L]
```